# How do I harden nginx to serve user-generated content?

Tags: nginx, users

nginx, is, as far as I know, relatively secure. I'm working on a site that lets users upload content to their own paths on the site. I use proxy_pass for my main site at /, but how should I configure my location block for `/users/`? So far I have the following, but is it secure for user-generated content? If yes, can you explain what ngnix does by default to do this? If not, what can I fix?

```
location /users/ {
    root /var/www/users
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is good because:

1. nginx only serves static content, as far as I know
2. nginx requires you to specifically enable php

Note: I'm not looking to scan the content, I'm looking to configure nginx to the most secure way to prevent php and other languages from executing. And yes, I do know the security implications otherwise with cookie grabbers but I use httponly cookies and set path to /

Comment: What type of content are you expecting from users to upload? What do you mean by *their own paths on the site*? Are they allowed to upload, lets say, custom javascript?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. I want them to be able to upload anything, kind of like s3 (this includes javascript). They can upload to a folder at `/var/www/users/<username>`, but I'm wondering if I can configure nginx to only serve static files, and that's it. (Nothing like php, etc. should be executed, just sent in the raw form to the requester).